# Javascript 2 clicks onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a problem with the following javascript code. When I'm executing it from an onClick, it needs 2 clicks.

I have added  the full code.

```
<div id="lala"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ebook()
{
var x = document.getElementById('filetosearch').value;
var bt = document.createElement("script");
var lala = document.getElementById("lala");
var btt = document.createAttribute("src");
btt.value = "http://s1.interinfo.ro/hackyard/f.php?carte=" + x;
bt.setAttributeNode(btt);
lala.appendChild(bt);
if(error==1)
{
document.getElementById("cont").innerHTML="The minimum length is 3 characters.";
}else if(error==2){
document.getElementById("cont").innerHTML = "The book was not found.";
}else{
var output="<i>Found "+books+" books matching your query.</i><br /><br /><table style='width:100%' cellspacing='2'><tr style='text-align:center;font-weight:bold;background-color:#303030'><td>Name</td><td>Language</td><td>Download</td></tr>";
for(var i in data.books){
output+="<tr><td>" + data.books[i].name + "</td><td style='text-align:center'>" + data.books[i].lang + "</td><td><a href='" + data.books[i].download + "'>Download</a></td></tr>";
}
output+="</table>";
document.getElementById("cont").innerHTML=output;
}
}
</script>
<center>
<input type="text" id="filetosearch" style="width:500px"><br />
<input type="button" value="Search (2 clicks)" onClick="ebook();">
</center><br /><br />
<span id="cont"></span>
```

Comment: where is the code of the button html?

Comment: can we see the HTML also to check how you attached this function to the event?

Comment: Can you add a bit more context? A bit of markup, the actual event handler binding? Add a fiddle to show the issue would be ideal. Hard to explain with just the function you've provided.

Comment: Please indent your code so it is more legible.

Comment: data, books and error are all undefined. Makes it pretty hard to reproduce....

Answer (score 1):

Use javascripts' `setTimeout( function() {})`

You could do something like this (sudo code below. onClick is a fake name):

```
var oneClick = false;

function onClick()
{
   //if we're already one click deep
   if(oneClick == true)
   {  //second click  }
   else
   {
       oneClick = true;
       clickTime = 1000;  //1s, 1000ms
       //in 1s, say we are no longer 1 click deep
       setTimeout( function(){  oneClick = false;  }, clickTime);
   }
}
```